# Should + Must combination query using NEST client for elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

I have a requirement to get data based on combination of properties with OR and AND combination and i am not able to get this query done. Help me with what it should be like in json and also using NEST client.

SQL query:

```
Select * 
From MySourceTable
Where (flag1 In ("Y","N") 
       And EntityStatus In ("STAT1", "STAT2") 
       And EntityType In ("T3"))
   Or (flag1 In ("N") And EntityType In ("T1", "T2"))
```

So far my query builds all must queries which resulted in fewer or none results. So theoretically I believe each query is MUST queries and all must queries have to be merged using OR.

Help me build json

Answer (score 1):

You are on a good way, the query will look something like

```
var searchResponse = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q =>
        (
            q.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Flag1.Suffix("keyword")).Terms("Y", "N")) &&
            q.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.EntityStatus.Suffix("keyword")).Terms("STAT1", "STAT2")) &&
            q.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.EntityType.Suffix("keyword")).Terms("T3"))
        ) ||
        (
            q.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.Flag1.Suffix("keyword")).Terms("N")) &&
            q.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.EntityType.Suffix("keyword")).Terms("T1", "T2"))
        )));
```

You didn't share your index mapping and query, so hard to say why your query didn't work.

**UPDATE**

You can compose such query dynamically using the following

```
var should = new QueryContainer();

should |=
    (
        new TermsQuery { Field = Infer.Field<EsDocument>(f => f.Flag1.Suffix("keyword")), Terms = new []{ "Y", "N" }} &&
        new TermsQuery { Field = Infer.Field<EsDocument>(f => f.EntityStatus.Suffix("keyword")), Terms = new []{ "STAT1", "STAT2" }} &&
        new TermsQuery { Field = Infer.Field<EsDocument>(f => f.EntityType.Suffix("keyword")), Terms = new []{ "T3" }}
        );
should |=
    (
        new TermsQuery { Field = Infer.Field<EsDocument>(f => f.Flag1.Suffix("keyword")), Terms = new []{ "N" }} &&
        new TermsQuery { Field = Infer.Field<EsDocument>(f => f.EntityType.Suffix("keyword")), Terms = new []{ "T1", "T2" }}
        );

var searchResponse = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => should));
```

Comment: the || queries are dynamic meaning i may have multiple or queries based on UI selections. So how do you make it dynamic?